# ASP.NET Core - Exception inside HealtCheck message

Tags: asp.net-core, health-monitoring

I'm wonder what is the purpose of exception parameter that we can pass to

```
HealthCheckResult.Unhealthy("Message", exception);
```

When this result is used in health-check endpoint only message and status are used and no info from exception?

Answer (score 0):

An Exception representing the exception that was thrown when checking for status. Optional.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.diagnostics.healthchecks.healthcheckresult.unhealthy?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.0

Here's a good explanation on how to use it:  https://blog.elmah.io/asp-net-core-2-2-health-checks-explained/

Comment: Ok I know docs and this article but when I'm passing this optional exception and then invoke health check endpoint  there is no information from exception